# Why isn’t there an article?

Tags: articles

> He turned to the right towards Capel Street. Ignatius Gallaher on
>   the London Press! Who would have thought it possible eight years
>   before? Still, now that he reviewed the past, Little Chandler could
>   remember many signs of future greatness in his friend. People used
>   to say that Ignatius Gallaher was wild Of course, he did mix with a
>   rakish set of fellows at that time. drank freely and borrowed
>   money on all sides. In the end he had got mixed up in some shady
>   affair, some money transaction: at least, that was one version of his
>   flight. But nobody denied him ***talent***. There was always a certain...
>   something in Ignatius Gallaher that impressed you in spite of
>   yourself. Even when he was out at elbows and at his wits' end for
>   money he kept up a bold face. Little Chandler remembered (and
>   the remembrance brought a slight flush of pride to his cheek) one
>   of Ignatius Gallaher's sayings when he was in a tight corner:
>
> "Half time now, boys," he used to say light-heartedly. "Where's my
>   considering cap?"
>
> -- [James Joyce, Dubliners](http://www.literaturecollection.com/a/james-joyce/dubliners/8/)

Does ***talent*** mean “people or a person with a natural ability to do something well ([OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/talent))” in this context? If so, why isn’t there an article before it?

Comment: Maybe it should've been *his* instead of *him* there.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - I don't know; I wouldn't venture to get out my red pen and edit Joyce.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a literary way of saying:

> But nobody denied *that he had* talent.

Yes, talent here means *the natural ability to do things well*.

This is a construct you are unlikely to hear in everyday speech, but you come across it every now and then in literature, particularly in the era when Joyce wrote, or earlier. I found a few instances with a Google book search. For example, from a biography published in 1884:

> There are many — not men of small calibre either — who believed these acts were impolitic, absolute mistakes; but **nobody denied him** the rewards of unmixed moral courage.

Again, this is a literary way of saying:

> Nobody denied that he earned the rewards of unmixed moral courage, even if he did make mistakes.

In other words, *everyone agreed that he was steadfast to his principles, and earned the rewards of that fine reputation*.

Also, from an 1801 work:

> **Nobody denied him** several brilliant qualities, considerable capacity, an agreeable turn of mind, manners at once noble and prepossessing, an easy and florid style of elocution...

which is a way of saying, *no one denied that he possessed several brilliant qualities...*

Lastly, from an 1898 publication:

> Generosity **no one denied him**...

which could be paraphrased, *everyone agreed he was generous.*

Similar phrasing can be found in more modern works, though. Published just this year:

> **No one denied her talent and intelligence**, but the other side of this coin was apparently an outrageous capacity for self-styling and display...

In other words, *everyone would admit she was talented and intelligent...*

However, it's hard to find a feminine counterpart to this construct in English, because the pronoun *her* maps to both *him* and *his*, so perhaps that one doesn't sound as awkward to the modern ear.

Comment: Then it's a kind of small clause or verbless clause.

Comment: @Listenever Yes, it's an abbreviated form of *no one denies him to have talent* or *no one denies him having talent*.

Comment: +1 But I don't think this is a historical thing: a) you'll find this use still current if you Google it in the present tense, "nobody denies him", and b) you'll find "denied **his**" talent/ability/etc. a lot more often than "denied **him**" in the 19th century, just as today. I think it's been true all along that we generally **prefer** *deny + objective*  when *deny* has the sense "prevent him from possessing" (*deny him  his right to...*) and *deny + genitive* when *deny* has the sense "declare he does not possess" (*deny his ability*).

Answer (score 3):

Nouns like *talent*, *ability*, *charisma*, *courage*, *generosity* are usually used without the article when we're talking about them as abstract personal qualities:

> He certainly has talent.
>   Nobody denies her courage.
>   Sartorius lacks generosity.

In these cases the predications can all easily be turned into simple adjectives:

> He is talented.
>   He is courageous.
>   Sartorius is not generous.

The article comes into play only when we want to define a particular instance or kind of the quality in play:

> He has a talent for spotting where the market is going.
>   She has the courage to defy convention and live life on her own terms.
>   Sartorius lacks the generosity most men of his wealth exhibit.