# Definite article before the name of a region

Tags: grammar, articles, grammaticality, definite-article, proper-nouns

If I want to write the name of a region like "(the) Middle East" or "(the) Northern Africa", do I have to put the definite article in front of that? Is there a general rule?

Thank you.

Comment: I would say "the Middle East" and not "the Northern Africa" and I don't know why I use "the" in one case and not the other!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The usage of the articles 'a' and 'the' for describing natural things](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13394/the-usage-of-the-articles-a-and-the-for-describing-natural-things)

Comment: "The Middle East" is not a determiner for "the East", but "Northern Africa" is a region of what we otherwise call "Africa" (and not "The Africa").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am speculating here.

I also say "the East Midlands" and not "the West Yorkshire" when referring to regions in England. That leads me to note that we say "the Midlands" and not "the Yorkshire".

So I speculate that the difference is that **Africa** and **Yorkshire** are formal names and we don't use "the" with formal names. We don't say

```
the David
```

we do say

```
the young man
```

**East** and **Midlands** are descriptive terms that have become nouns.

Comment: I like this speculation, thanks.