# He died in (a/the/-) prison

Tags: articles

> [Prison(noun)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prison)
>
> A building to which people are legally committed as a punishment for a crime or while awaiting trial:
>
> He died in prison.
>
> Both men were sent to prison.

Why not *He died in a prison*? And is it possible to say *He died in the prison* if I want to talk abount the prison in which he died?

Are there any other noun with this characteristic?

Comment: This is the same question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital. Also here http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10479/how-do-i-know-when-to-use-the-versus-a-versus-%E2%88%85-as-an-article-on-a-noun (point 8)

Comment: In my view, *in prison* describes a status more than a place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swan's PEU (3rd Edition) has an entry for this. It reads...

> In some common fixed expressions to do with places, time and movement, normally countable nouns are treated as uncountable, **without articles.** - *Swan's Practical English Usage, Entry 70.*

Those common expressions include - *to/at/in/from school/university/college*; *to/in/into/out of bed/prison.*; *at/from home.*

Note: It specifies: in BrE, *hospital* does not take article. Good discussion about that topic is [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital), as mentioned by fluffy.

Comment: But there are situations where the use of an article is possible, even with those words. _There is the school that burned down last year_. _The governor built a new prison_. But even _He died in the prison that he built himself!_ or _He died in a prison that had been kept functioning only for his sake_ .

Comment: Answer updated. However, I'd not prefer using *a/the* prison in last two examples of yours.

Comment: You may prefer not to, but grammatically, it is needed. _He died in prison that he built himself._ is not grammatical.

Comment: Trying to understand Swan's approach there. Any clue about the entry 70 then?

Comment: Yups. He died in _the_ prison that he built himself is _not_ a _certain fixed expression_ as meant by Swan. The fixed expression is _in prison_, not _in <some adjectives> prison <some more stuff about the prison>_. So he is _in prison_, but he is _in a big prison_, _in a prison that will be closed soon_.

Comment: @oerkelens But that's what both the OP's examples are all about! Fixed expression, aren't they?

Comment: My point was that you only omit the article _in those exact expressions_. Your answer seemed to indicate you would never use articles with words like "prison" (and you seemed to interpret Swan in that way exactly!). I just intended to note that _that_ simply was not true.

Comment: So normally, it's *He died in prison*, but with an appropriate context, *a* and *the* are also possible or even needed. Right?

Comment: @SantiSantichaivekin: Correct :)

Comment: *In prison* doesn't refer to a single prison, but to the state of being in a prison.  If you need to refer to a prison rather than the state, as in oerkelens' example, the version without articles can't be used.  In other words, the alternatives are different semantically.

Comment: Hmnnnn then, is *He died in a prison* incorrect? Or it is correct but less used?

Comment: *He died in prison* is correct. To understand snailplane's comment, check answer [by caxtontype here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital).