# Definite article vs zero article

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

I have problems with definite and zero articles in the following sentences:

- "I met a man you were talking about over **THE** telephone yesterday."
- "The wounded were examined by **THE** doctor and sent to **PRISON**."

These examples are from my textbook. The textbook says that these articles should be set this way. I don't understand why. Namely:

- Why in the first sentence we use "the telephone" while in the second "prison" with zero article? Why are they different?
- Is it grammatically correct to say "The wounded were examined by **DOCTOR** and sent to **THE** prison?" For example, in case the prison is before the eyes of a speaker.

I am looking for a strong grammatical reference. Simple rules-of-the-thumb proved to be inadequate, I cannot answer my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to read [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151311/a-doctor-vs-the-doctor) question about doctors and [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31888/he-died-in-a-the-prison) one about prisons.

We say "on the telephone" and "on the radio", but "on television". The answers to [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/176124/why-on-television-but-on-the-radio) question try to explain this curious discrepancy!

Comment: My parents' generation used to say "on the television". There's a whole Monty Python sketch based on the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

The definite article is used when referring to something *specific*. There are many telephones in the world - your telephone is a specific one. You would use the definite article with 'prison' if you were speaking about a specific prison, for example "*the prison nearby holds 1000 prisoners*".

The 'zero article' is used with *mass nouns* - when referring to the things in general. For example, "*water is a liquid*" means *all* water. It is common to use 'prison' as a mass noun when referring to the prison system as a whole, or to the concept of being imprisoned, for example, "*he is in prison*". Actually, 'telephone' can be used that way, too - for example "*we communicate **by** telephone*".

Comment: It's not about specific items; it's an idiomatic usage. You can say "Scott called me on the telephone" without referring to a specific telephone; "on the telephone" is an idiomatic expression that means the same as "by telephone". Similarly "I got there on the train" doesn't mean a specific train, it just means you went on some train that goes there.