# Why have I to use zero article in a question?

Tags: zero-article

Why do we not use article before noun fruit in this question?

> Do you like fruit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know when to use "the" versus "a" versus "∅" as an article on a noun?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10479/how-do-i-know-when-to-use-the-versus-a-versus-%e2%88%85-as-an-article-on-a-noun)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the sentence is a question is not relevant. We would use a zero article (that is, no article, definite or indefinite) in a statement also: I like fruit, Jack likes fruit, we like fruit, my stove burns coal, my dog eats meat.

We use the zero article before a mass (uncountable) noun. 'Fruit' here is a mass noun.

The same is true when the noun is plural but of indefinite number: the boy loves to play with toys.

[The Zero Article in English Grammar](https://www.thoughtco.com/zero-article-grammar-1692619#:%7E:text=In%20general%2C%20no%20article%20is,where%20the%20reference%20is%20indefinite.&text=In%20addition%2C%20linguists%20have%20found,done%20to%20express%20non%2Dspecificity.)

Answer (score 1):

We do not use an article for a general assertion or question. So, when asking “Do you like fruit?” this is a general question that could mean any type of fruit. The answer could be “Yes, I like fruit. My favorite fruit is watermelon.” On the other hand, if you were to present a bowl of fruit to a dinner guest, while they are eating you can “Do you like the/this/that fruit?” since you are referring to a specific bowl/piece of fruit that is in front of you. The answer could be “Yeah, this fruit is very fresh and sweet!”

“Do you like blueberries?” is a general question while inquiring about someone’s preferences, but on the other hand “Do you like these blueberries?” would be appropriate when asking about a specific container of blueberries that you are serving to someone. (if these specific ones are too soft, firm, sour, sweet, etc)